# Idiom use of Conan to consume packages by CMake build system

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, packaging, conan

In Conan [documentation](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.5/integrations/cmake/cmake_find_package_generator.html) for cmake_find_package generator, it is mentioned that :

> In the CMakeList.txt you do not need to specify or include anything related with Conan at all, just rely on the find_package feature

In my [case](https://github.com/omarekik/MazeCli), after calling `find_package(boost COMPONENTS boost program_options REQUIRED)` in [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/omarekik/MazeCli/blob/main/maze/config/CMakeLists.txt) of config module, the `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` variable was empty (undefined) so that CMake failed to build due to boost missing header file <boost/program_options.hpp> included in StartupConfig.cpp.
The only workaround I found is to `include(FindBoost.cmake)` in the root [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/omarekik/MazeCli/blob/main/maze/CMakeLists.txt).
If I comment the `include(FindBoost.cmake)` and change boost by Boost in the find_package, I get the following build error :

```
maze/0.1.0: Calling build()
maze/0.1.0: CMake command: cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/root/.conan/data/maze/0.1.0/_/_/build/5f5fdaf06f8bd18961521dbe87621377ba962aa5/conan_toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/root/.conan/data/maze/0.1.0/_/_/package/5f5fdaf06f8bd18961521dbe87621377ba962aa5" "/root/.conan/data/maze/0.1.0/_/_/build/5f5fdaf06f8bd18961521dbe87621377ba962aa5"
Using Conan toolchain: /root/.conan/data/maze/0.1.0/_/_/build/5f5fdaf06f8bd18961521dbe87621377ba962aa5/conan_toolchain.cmake.
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Conan: Component target declared 'GTest::gtest'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'GTest::gtest_main'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'GTest::gmock'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'GTest::gmock_main'
-- Conan: Target declared 'gtest::gtest'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::headers'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::_boost_cmake'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::diagnostic_definitions'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::disable_autolinking'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::dynamic_linking'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::_libboost'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::atomic'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::container'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::date_time'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::exception'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::math'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::math_c99'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::math_c99f'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::math_c99l'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::math_tr1'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::math_tr1f'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::math_tr1l'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::program_options'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::regex'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::serialization'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::stacktrace'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::stacktrace_addr2line'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::stacktrace_backtrace'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::stacktrace_basic'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::stacktrace_noop'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::system'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::test'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::test_exec_monitor'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::wserialization'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::chrono'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::filesystem'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::nowide'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::prg_exec_monitor'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::random'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::thread'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::timer'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::type_erasure'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::unit_test_framework'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::wave'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::context'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::contract'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::coroutine'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::fiber'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::fiber_numa'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::graph'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::iostreams'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::locale'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::log'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'boost::log_setup'
-- Conan: Target declared 'boost::boost'
-- Conan: Target declared 'bzip2::bzip2'
-- Conan: Target declared 'ZLIB::ZLIB'
-- Conan: Target declared 'libbacktrace::libbacktrace'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'GTest::gtest'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'GTest::gtest_main'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'GTest::gmock'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'GTest::gmock_main'
-- Conan: Target declared 'gtest::gtest'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'GTest::gtest'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'GTest::gtest_main'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'GTest::gmock'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'GTest::gmock_main'
-- Conan: Target declared 'gtest::gtest'
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /root/.conan/data/maze/0.1.0/_/_/build/5f5fdaf06f8bd18961521dbe87621377ba962aa5
maze/0.1.0: CMake command: cmake --build '/root/.conan/data/maze/0.1.0/_/_/build/5f5fdaf06f8bd18961521dbe87621377ba962aa5' '--' '-j12'
[  7%] Building CXX object config/CMakeFiles/Configs.dir/src/StartupConfig.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object generator/CMakeFiles/Generator.dir/src/MazeGenerator.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object solver/CMakeFiles/Solver.dir/src/MazeSolver.cpp.o
/root/.conan/data/maze/0.1.0/_/_/build/5f5fdaf06f8bd18961521dbe87621377ba962aa5/config/src/StartupConfig.cpp:5:10: fatal error: boost/program_options.hpp: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <boost/program_options.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [config/CMakeFiles/Configs.dir/build.make:76: config/CMakeFiles/Configs.dir/src/StartupConfig.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:203: config/CMakeFiles/Configs.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Do I miss a configuration in [ConanFile](https://github.com/omarekik/MazeCli/blob/main/maze/conanfile.py) ?
Could you propose more idiomatic way so that CMake find packages as required in ConanFile ?

Comment: The proper spelling is `find_package(Boost ...)`, not  `find_package(boost ...)`.

Comment: The full output also helps, it is likely that it is not finding because of a wrong name (use ``Boost``), but it could also be that you are not passing the toolchain if building as a consumer directly with ``cmake ... -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake``, or something like that.

Comment: Please place `set( Boost_DEBUG ON)` in your CMakeLists.txt. It should give you more information on what's going on.

Comment: @Tsyvarev
Changing boost by Boost doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Jellyboy Actually, I added the error message to the description.

Comment: According to the output, the Conan's version of `find_package(Boost)` defines **targets** instead of variables like `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS` or `Boost_LIBRARIES`. So, you could link with Boost using target `boost::boost`. That linkage will also provide Boost include directories.

Comment: @Tsyvarev this is what I did. In https://github.com/omarekik/MazeCli/blob/main/maze/config/CMakeLists.txt   
you will find this line : target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE boost::boost boost::program_options) . But headerfile of boost not found.

Comment: @drodi I added the error message in the description. The conan cmake.build() will launch the command with DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/root/.conan/data/maze/0.1.0/_/_/build/5f5fdaf06f8bd18961521dbe87621377ba962aa5/conan_toolchain.cmake"

Comment: @omarekik: `INTERFACE` linkage doesn't add include directories for the library itself. Instead use `PUBLIC` or `PRIVATE` linkage: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC boost::boost boost::program_options)`.

Comment: Unless you need to be able to build without Conan you might find https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan and using [CMAKE_TARGETS](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan#cmake_targets) simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed by [@Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev), changing INTERFACE by PRIVATE in `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE boost::boost boost::program_options)` resolved my issue.
For more details, I recommend reading this clarification about CMake scope meaning:
https://leimao.github.io/blog/CMake-Public-Private-Interface/